# Как сказать "лихие девяностые" на английском?

Tags: узус

I honestly don't know. Gave it some thought, but best i could come up with is `Roaring 90s`,`Dashing 90s`?

Those familiar with a term - what do you think?

Comment: Your question is for ell.stackexchange. com

Answer (score 3):

Depending on a context, I'd choose between the following:

***no man's 90s***

***wild wild 90s***

***thrilling 90s***

***threatening 90s***

***mad 90s***

***chaotic 90s***

***naughty 90s***

***nasty 90s***

***crazy 90s***